# setup jdk error in android studio Error in Java

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

[this image is android studio error in java editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igC3h.png)

this is happens after windows Updating and restarting in Windows 10.
my pc restart automatically for updates and then i saw this errors in android studio.
when i use Ctrl_space for hint it shows "setup JDK"
[Ctrl+space for hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9GU9.png)
when i click on it popup will display with "select SDK".

after select and restart got same error lines.

this red lines are in all projects.
i tried it with gradle sync and pc restart and android studio restart.
please help me to solve this.

fixed --

This Problem happens when

> Android Studio unexpectedly closed or stopped due to power cut or
> force stop from Task Manager many reasons.

Solution for this Problem is `invalidate caches and Restart Android Studio`. No need to reinstall Android Studio or JDK. if error is Gradle related than Go to .gradle folder in Project root folder and delete it and regenerate the gradle file using re-sync.

Comment: Did you try setting up the JDK?

Comment: i tried it!i is in same path
have you seen scrshots?

Comment: The files may be there, but that doesn't mean that Android Studio doesn't need reconfigured. I see a bunch of errors and a popup dialog. What happens when you select an SDK?

Comment: just building project!

Comment: Well, the problem is clearly that the project became misconfigured. Can you make a new blank project and make it work?

Comment: i also tried it.
i am in this problem within 4 hours.

Comment: Reinstall Java and/or Android Studio?

Comment: this is android studio problem i think.
ok this took some more time.
i will ping after reinstalling.
thanks btw.

Comment: I don't think so. Android Studio is correctly identifying the problem, which I think is that the windows registry and environment variables got reset during the upgrade

Comment: might be possible.
reinstalling jdk...

Comment: :-(  same error.
i will try on updating android studio by tomorrow.
thanks for replay.

Comment: finally this is solved with reinstalling android studio.
thanks for Help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to reconfigure location of JDK as it was changed after update and IDE can't find it in last location. Remove SDK config from IDE and add it back.

Comment: i tried it but not working!

with the sdk update and jsk update.

Answer (score 0):

Re-configure your `System Variables`. The system somehow lost the variable pointing to your JDK or the `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: well i tried this before but not working.
now i m reinstalling jdk..\

Comment: open cmd then type `javac -version` then tell me the response